# How to transfer Bitcoin Cash from a multi-sig vault?

Tags: multi-signature, bitcoin-cash

I have two private keys for a multi-sig vault. I have a tool that will sign transactions to move BTC out of this address.

Where can I find a tool that will use my two private keys to move BCC (Bitcoin Cash) out of this address? I want to move this BCC to an exchange for trading.

For the curious: this multi-sig vault was created via coinbase. And while their official position is that they don't give users access to their BCC, since I have control of two private keys I can move BTC out without their cooperation, so I should be able to do the same with BCC in that same address. [Coinbase's own tool](https://github.com/coinbase/multisig-tool) only works with BTC, so perhaps a fork of it that works with BCC would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long, painstaking process, I developed the manual steps required and thoroughly documented it here:

[How to sell your Coinbase Multi-sig wallet coins on the Bitcoin Cash (BCC) network](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2017/08/how-to-sell-your-coinbase-multi-sig.html)

Comment: Great work. I have knowledge how to build transactions for BCC network but I do not have any coins on msig-vault coinbase account to create user-friendly tool

Answer (score 1):

You should

1) create a transaction which spends funds from your wallet and sign it with SIGHASH_FORKID bit https://github.com/bitcoincashorg/spec/blob/master/replay-protected-sighash.md

2) send this transaction to BCC network using BCC-client and wait this transaction to be confirmed

Unfortunately, I do not know about the existanse of automated tool for this task - you should do it yourself.